# (CSS Only)Change parent when a new child is dynamically created

Tags: css, sass, parent-child, onchange

Is there a way to detect if a new child has been created in a parent with only css(scss/sass)?

I have the following code

```
.toast-bottom-right:hover {
  max-height: 40%;
}

.toast-bottom-right:not(:hover) > .toast-error:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}

.toast-bottom-right:not(:hover){
  animation: collapse 2s 1s forwards;
}

.toast-bottom-right {
  max-height: 40%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;
}

.toast-bottom-right::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

@keyframes collapse{
  from  {
    max-height: 40%;
  }
  to {
    max-height: 1.5%;
  }
}
```

This popups a parent element on hover(with that all the children), then when the hover goes off all children element but the first are hidden. And after a second the parent max height gets set to a small size(1.5%) which causes the parent to become just a small bar. Which can then be hovered on.

My goal is to change the parents max height to its original state (40%) when a new child is added and after 5 seconds the animation to unhover starts again

**The concrete question:** is there anyway to achieve this, or something close to this with only css(scss/sass)?